# React-router-dom nested routes not working with ProtectedRoute/PrivateRoute

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

This is my first time jumping in react-router-dom, My nested routes are working fine but every time I refresh the page it does not maintain the child route where it goes back to the root page instead.

**App.tsx**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback={<div></div>}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/feed" component={Feed} />
        </Switch>
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Feed.tsx**

```
const Feed: React.FC<any> = () => {
    let { path } = useRouteMatch();
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row justify-content-center p-5">
                <div className="col-md-7">
                    <NavbarMini />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-4">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos officia quisquam commodi molestias labore assumenda, amet ea pariatur aspernatur accusamus!
                </div>
                <div className="col-md">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path={`${path}`} component={Home} />
                        <Route path={`${path}/posts`} component={Posts} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I recently found out that my ProtectedRoute is the reason why I cannot maintain my path every time I refresh the page. How do I make this right?

**ProtectedRoute**

```
const ProtectedRoute: React.FC<IProtectedRoute> = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    const authentication = useSelector((state: any) => state.authentication);
    const { isAuthenticated, loading } = authentication;
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props => !isAuthenticated && !loading
                ? <Redirect to="/login" />
                : <Component  {...props} />
            } />
    )

}
```

This is my first time jumping in a library, Sorry for this noob problem.
**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: It is much preferred to include your code as text in the question instead of screenshots, for readability, allowing people to cut-and-paste, etc.

Comment: Sorry, Will update my post.